# is nested chunks in spring batch possible

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Hi I am new to spring batch .

I have situation with spring batch like below :

I need to run a batch for all Promotions [ List of Promotions]

- For Each Promotion I need to prepare dynamic query with promotion attributes and get all the transaction history and compute promotional points to each user

  And here the with above dynamic query I wanted to read again from batch  as it returns results minimum of 50 thousand records .

below is the process I am expecting, is this is possible in spring batch?

- Read Promotions[Reader reads promotions one by one]

  - create query and put it on context
  - pass it to the next reader

    - reader reads transactions one by one
    - process transactions and calculate points
  - processor

My problem here is Not able write nested chunks [ one for read promotions and one for reading transactions].

One alternative is :

Partition the job for each Promotion , in this all promotions will run concurrently , But we need to run one after one .

Can any body  suggest any way for this ?

Comment: Did you find another solution? I'm interested because, not too far in time, I will face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can't have nested chunk so you can code your own CompositeItemReader like(pseudo-code):

```
class CompositeItemReader implements ItemReader<Transaction> {
  ItemReader<Promotion> promotions;
  ItemReader<Transaction> transactions;

  public void setPromotions(ItemReader<Promotion> promotions) {...}

  public Transaction read() {
    Transaction item = transactions.read();
    if(null == item) {
      Promotion p = promotions.read();
      if(null != p) {
        // Close transactions reader, create dynamic query and open transaction reader
        // Re-read item!
        item = this.read();
      }
    }

   return item;
  }
}
```

but remember to register promotions and transactions as stream and remember to manage restartability.
Or, if you are sure each Promotion have a limited List<> of associated Transactions, you can use a `ItemProcessor<Promotion,List<Transaction>>` that convert a single Promotion like (Driving Query Based ItemReaders):

```
class PromotionProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Promotion,List<Transaction>> {
  public List<Transaction> process(Promotion item) {
    Query q = <create dynamic query>;
    return q.list();
  }
}
```

Else a solution based on PeekableItemReader and data holder like one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303106/spring-batch-aggregated-reader-writer-issue?rq=1)

Hope this considerations can be helpful! Good job!