# spring batch itemreader read multiple lines and dynamic chunk size

Tags: spring, spring-batch

there is one case to handle more than 3M records which in the flat file, and we want to read 3k records one time and then process it to writer, is there any better way to process that? beside that, we have some other conditions, since our flat file format like below:

userid1, transaction1
userid1, transaction2
userid1, transaction3
userid2, transaction1
userid2, transaction3

one user may have many transactions, the item reader will read the transaction for one user to different threads, we want to put all the transaction for this user in the same thread, so we want to dynamically change the chunksize, so is there any better way for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer at your question:
yes, you can change `commit-size` using `scope` step and properties substitution with #{} syntax or declaring a custom `completion-policy`.

But I think you don't need to change `commit-size` but implements a custom reader that build up a domain object with all transactions for a single user.

```
class UserTransaction {
  String transactionId;
}
class UserWithTransaction {
  String user;
  List<UserTransaction> transactions;
}

class UserWithTransactionReader implements ItemReader<UserWithTransaction> {...}
```

There are a lot of custom reader implementation around the net (and here in SO) that build a complex object from a CSV file (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199192/record-splitting-and-grouping-in-spring-batch/25199527#25199527) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303106/spring-batch-aggregated-reader-writer-issue?lq=1))

Comment: How to mapping the Object UserWithTransactions?

Comment: In the AggregatePeekableReader, where do we define the method "hasSameInvoiceNumberAndVendorNumber" for T?

Comment: I gave you an idea about how to achieve your goal; I can't write code for you because I don't known you domain data,file format,business concern and more. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836689/spring-batch-multi-line-record-item-writer-with-variable-number-of-lines-per-rec and SB samples and do some tries.

Comment: Thank you Ricci, I have thought out the way to resolve the cases.